# Clojure Yesql not able to find queries file

Tags: vim, clojure

I'm trying to use Kris Jenkins's Yesql library in my test Clojure project. I've created a sample `queries.sql` file with a single query. Single `core.clj` file looks like this (`precalc` is the name of the test project):

```
(ns precalc.core)
(require '[yesql.core :refer [defqueries defquery]])

(println (defqueries "resources/queries.sql"))
(defquery col-type "resources/queries.sql")
(slurp "resources/queries.sql")
```

When attempting to evaluate e.g. line 4, I get

`;!!CompilerException java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources/queries.sql, compiling:(precalc/core.clj:4:10)`

I've tried putting `queries.sql` into root project folder as well, but to no avail. Slurping works though. My mistake must be very obvious. Can someone please help?

I use Leiningen's repl, Macvim and Tim Pope's vim-fireplace plugin, connected via cider-nrepl.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The file has to be on your classpath which you can show using

```
lein classpath
```

Look at the first few entries, they'll look similar to these:

```
/git/project/test:/git/project/src:/git/project/dev-resources:/git/project/resources:...
```

Since you already put it into `resources`, you're set. The important point, however, is that the path you pass to `defqueries` has to be *relative* to your classpath, so in your case relative to `resources`:

```
(defqueries "queries.sql")
```

`slurp` works because it operates directly on your filesystem, not only on the classpath. Since you started your REPL in the project root, `resources/queries.sql` is a perfectly valid path.

Comment: Wow! It works! Thanks! I was not aware that Yesql would need relative paths. I was chasing it in the wrong places - lein classpath does not contain project root folder, so i was fooled into thinking that moving queries.sql to the root was actually doing something.